# php while loop running only once

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

I have a php script for check the availability of some data. I call this script from external jquery. the jquery is running fine. here is my php:

```
<?php


$avares = checkAva($fi_nm, $tbl_nm, $txtval);

echo $avares;

function checkAva($field, $table, $curval) {

$avres = mysql_query("SELECT " . $field . " FROM " . $table . "") or die("query failed");

while ($a_row = mysql_fetch_array($avres)) {
    $dbval = $a_row[$field];

    if ($curval == $dbval) {
        return "no";
    } else {
        return "yes";
    }
}
}

?>
```

$curval is the variable coming from external jquery. my problem is that the while loop seems to run only once though there are lot of entries in the DB. I checked it with an integer variable and the while loop seems to run only once. can you help me to solve that?

Comment: no wonder, you are returning in the loop

Comment: you should assign yes or no to a variable and return that variable after while loop

Comment: though I removed the return and used a variable my while loop only running once. I counted it with increment variable.

Comment: where did you return that variable, outside while loop ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at your code.

```
while ($a_row = mysql_fetch_array($avres)) {
    $dbval = $a_row[$field];

    if ($curval == $dbval) {
        return "no";
    } else {
        return "yes";
    }
}
```

you have used return, if its true it returns and false then also returns change those according to your needs. The return statement immediately ends execution of the current function

Comment: I did. used break; but that's not the problem. the while loop running only once is the problem.

Comment: Remove the return statements from your code and then var_dump($dbval) on each iteration. JJPA has a very strong arguement.

Comment: The problem may be your understanding of php mechanisms first. I suggest you should learn a bit about some basis of the language.

Comment: yes. sorry about that. removed return from inside while loop and it worked alright.

Comment: @user3383167 Good to know that you are solved. Keep [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/) always with you its really help ful

Answer (score 1):

It will by design as you have a return statement. From what you have said your not actually wanting it to return but to set a variable that at end of execution will return no or yes. I could be wrong on this but hey ho.

```
<?php
echo checkAva($fi_nm, $tbl_nm, $txtval);

function checkAva($field, $table, $curval) {
    $avres = mysql_query("SELECT " . $field . " FROM " . $table) or die("query failed");

    $noOrYes = "yes";
    while ($a_row = mysql_fetch_array($avres)) {
        if($curval == $a_row[$field]) {
            $noOrYes = "no";
        }
    }

    return $noOrYes;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The possible issue that can cause Loop to iterate once are:

1. Error in the Variable used for the $query and $result
2. Same name Variable inside and outside of the Loop
3. Incorrect placement of Return statement
4. Invalid Mysql Statement

Answer (score 0):

Directly put the condition in your Query like

```
function checkAva($field, $table, $curval) {

    $avres = mysql_query("SELECT " . $field . " FROM " . $table . " 
                          WHERE `".$field."` = '".$curVal."'");
    $res = mysql_fetch_array($avres);
    if(is_array($res) && count($res) > 0)
        return "Yes";
    else
        return "No";
}
```

Instead of getting all the results and checking with each one of the result you directly put a condition to extract the results which satisfies your condition.This will be suggestable if you have many records.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put one of the return outside of the while loop.
For example if you just wanted to check if $curval == $dbval

```
while ($a_row = mysql_fetch_array($avres)) {
    $dbval = $a_row[$field];

    //If the condition was met return with a no
    if ($curval == $dbval) {
       return "no";
    }
}
//If the condition was not met return yes
return yes;
```

That's basically what you need to do so the loop will run until your condition was met or not at all.