# Change array in foreach

Tags: php, arrays

I'm editing my array in a foreach, but when I return the values I get only one array as the result and not my 500 events.

Can someone explain why I can't get my 500 array's?

```
private function getEventsScroll($param = null)
{


$sql = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM events WHERE date >= NOW() AND status = "0" ORDER BY `date` ASC');

$sql->execute();
$events = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach ($events as &$event) {

    $output = [
        'name' => setHalveText(ucfirst($event['name']), 17),
        'sub_text' => setHalveText($event['sub_text'], 45),
        'datetime' => getDaytimeFormat($event['date'], 'Y-m-d\TH:i:s.u'),
        'dayNumber' => getDaytimeFormat($event['date'], 'd'),
        'monthName' => getDaytimeFormat($event['date'], 'F'),
        'year' => getDaytimeFormat($event['date'], 'l'),
        'time_start' => setTime($event['time_start']),
        'time_end' => setTime($event['time_start']),
        'url' => '../../event/' . setUuid($event['uid']) . ':'. getEventSlug($event['name']), 
    ];
    unset($event['name']);
    unset($event['sub_text']);
    unset($event['time_start']);
    unset($event['time_end']);

    $event = array_merge($event, $output);

    return $event;
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove this line `return $event;` and change this `foreach ($events as $event) {` to `foreach ($events as &$event) {` and try again

Comment: Because you don't understand the meaning of `return`.

Comment: I use return because it is in a function ?

Comment: Well put your return outside of your foreach loop

Comment: and also change `return $event` to `return $events`

Comment: @VuralAcar because OP is altering his array side by side using `$event = array_merge($event, $output);` take a look

Comment: I voted to close for another reason, but should have nominated a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22374960/php-while-loop-running-only-once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do it like below (changes are commented):-

```
private function getEventsScroll($param = null){

    $sql = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM events WHERE date >= NOW() AND status = "0" ORDER BY `date` ASC');

    $sql->execute();
    $events = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    foreach ($events as &$event) {

        $output = [
            'name' => setHalveText(ucfirst($event['name']), 17),
            'sub_text' => setHalveText($event['sub_text'], 45),
            'datetime' => getDaytimeFormat($event['date'], 'Y-m-d\TH:i:s.u'),
            'dayNumber' => getDaytimeFormat($event['date'], 'd'),
            'monthName' => getDaytimeFormat($event['date'], 'F'),
            'year' => getDaytimeFormat($event['date'], 'l'),
            'time_start' => setTime($event['time_start']),
            'time_end' => setTime($event['time_start']),
            'url' => '../../event/' . setUuid($event['uid']) . ':'. getEventSlug($event['name']), 
        ];
        unset($event['name']);
        unset($event['sub_text']);
        unset($event['time_start']);
        unset($event['time_end']);

        array_merge($event, $output);

    }

    return $events; //return at last
}
```